# Is function's integral always equal to its primitive

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, continuity

If we take function

$$ F(x) = \cases{x^2 \sin\frac{1}{x^2} & $x \ne 0$ \\ 0 & $x=0$ }$$
whose derivative is
$$ f(x) = \cases{2x\sin\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2}{x}\cos\frac{1}{x^2} & $x \ne 0$
\\ 0 & $x=0$}$$

Even though $f$ is not continuous at $0$, $F$ is a continuous primitive of $f$ on any open interval containing $0$. Does that imply that $f$ integrable as well on any closed interval containing $0$, with:

$$\int f(x) dx = F(x) + C$$

Comment: What do you mean by integrable here? It has a primitive. But being integrable usually has a different meaning.

Comment: How is f continuous here?

Comment: You've shown that the derivative of $F$ is $f$, which means by definition that $\int f(x)dx = F(x) + C$. I don't see what the question is other than this. As noted in a comment above, the word "integrable" usually means something different (existence of definite integral), but you seem to ask about indefinite integrals and so the answer to your question is simply yes, by the definition of what $\int f(x)dx$ means.

Comment: As @Snaw said, I thought that by definition $\int F'(x) dx = F(x) + C$, but I was not sure if that definition required bounded $F'(x)$ or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Riemann or Lebesgue integration having an antiderivative is not sufficient to show integrability. A similar function, $\frac 1x\sin \frac 1{x^3}$, is an example that is not Lebesgue integrable (and therefore not Riemann integrable) on intervals containing $0$.

But for the [Kurzweil-Henstock integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral), if a function $F$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ with at most countably many exceptions, then $F'$ is Kurzweil-Henstock integrable over any sub-interval and $$\int_c^dF'(x)\,dx = F(d) - F(c)$$ for all $c,d \in [a,b]$.

---

On the other hand, since this $f$ is continuous everywhere but $0$, by the FTC, it is Riemann integrable on $[\epsilon, b]$ and $[a,-\epsilon]$ for all $a < 0 < b, 0 < \epsilon < \min \{-a, b\}$, with $$\int_a^{-\epsilon} f(x)\,dx = F(-\epsilon) - F(a)\\\int_\epsilon^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(\epsilon)$$
And since $F$ is continuous at $0$, the improper Riemann integrals exist and $$\int_a^0 f(x)\,dx = F(0) - F(a)\\\int_0^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(0)\\\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \int_a^0 f(x)\,dx + \int_0^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a)$$
So for the Riemann case, as long as you allow improper Riemann integration, yes this particular $f$ is Riemann integrable over $0$, with $F$ as its integral. As Improper-Riemann integrable $\implies$ Lebesgue integrable, it works for Lebesgue integration as well.

Comment: I remember hearing about the Kurzweil-Henstock integral a long time ago (when I was 13 years old or so) and then never using it. It is a really cool integral!

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch - I'm in favor of just teaching KH integration in calculus (it is only a small change from Riemann) and letting the Riemann integral go the same way as the Cauchy integral before it. Lebesgue integration covers different territory, so it still is very useful. But Riemann is entirely replaceble by KH.